# NetworkImageView not loading the image from the first time

Tags: android, imageview, navigation-drawer, android-volley

I'm trying to upload an Image from my API to show it as profile picture, the problem is from the first time that the user opens the navdrawer the image doesn't load and it makes the entire layout disappear, but from the second time it all works, and I notice that it happens when the width of the image is less than the height. This is the class that I'm using:

```
public class CircledNetworkImageView extends ImageView {

    public boolean mCircled;

    /**
     * The URL of the network image to load
     */
    private String mUrl;

    /**
     * Resource ID of the image to be used as a placeholder until the network image is loaded.
     */
    private int mDefaultImageId;

    /**
     * Resource ID of the image to be used if the network response fails.
     */
    private int mErrorImageId;

    /**
     * Local copy of the ImageLoader.
     */
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    /**
     * Current ImageContainer. (either in-flight or finished)
     */
    private ImageLoader.ImageContainer mImageContainer;

    public CircledNetworkImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CircledNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CircledNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    /**
     * Sets URL of the image that should be loaded into this view. Note that calling this will
     * immediately either set the cached image (if available) or the default image specified by
     * {@link CircledNetworkImageView#setDefaultImageResId(int)} on the view.
     * <p/>
     * NOTE: If applicable, {@link CircledNetworkImageView#setDefaultImageResId(int)} and
     * {@link CircledNetworkImageView#setErrorImageResId(int)} should be called prior to calling
     * this function.
     *
     * @param url         The URL that should be loaded into this ImageView.
     * @param imageLoader ImageLoader that will be used to make the request.
     */
    public void setImageUrl(String url, ImageLoader imageLoader) {
        mUrl = url;
        mImageLoader = imageLoader;
        // The URL has potentially changed. See if we need to load it.
        loadImageIfNecessary(false);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the default image resource ID to be used for this view until the attempt to load it
     * completes.
     */
    public void setDefaultImageResId(int defaultImage) {
        mDefaultImageId = defaultImage;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the error image resource ID to be used for this view in the event that the image
     * requested fails to load.
     */
    public void setErrorImageResId(int errorImage) {
        mErrorImageId = errorImage;
    }

    /**
     * Loads the image for the view if it isn't already loaded.
     *
     * @param isInLayoutPass True if this was invoked from a layout pass, false otherwise.
     */
    void loadImageIfNecessary(final boolean isInLayoutPass) {
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        ScaleType scaleType = getScaleType();

        boolean wrapWidth = false, wrapHeight = false;
        if (getLayoutParams() != null) {
            wrapWidth = getLayoutParams().width == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            wrapHeight = getLayoutParams().height == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        }

        // if the view's bounds aren't known yet, and this is not a wrap-content/wrap-content
        // view, hold off on loading the image.
        boolean isFullyWrapContent = wrapWidth && wrapHeight;
        if (width == 0 && height == 0 && !isFullyWrapContent) {
            return;
        }

        // if the URL to be loaded in this view is empty, cancel any old requests and clear the
        // currently loaded image.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mUrl)) {
            if (mImageContainer != null) {
                mImageContainer.cancelRequest();
                mImageContainer = null;
            }
            setDefaultImageOrNull();
            return;
        }

        // if there was an old request in this view, check if it needs to be canceled.
        if (mImageContainer != null && mImageContainer.getRequestUrl() != null) {
            if (mImageContainer.getRequestUrl().equals(mUrl)) {
                // if the request is from the same URL, return.
                return;
            } else {
                // if there is a pre-existing request, cancel it if it's fetching a different URL.
                mImageContainer.cancelRequest();
                setDefaultImageOrNull();
            }
        }

        // Calculate the max image width / height to use while ignoring WRAP_CONTENT dimens.
        int maxWidth = wrapWidth ? 0 : width;
        int maxHeight = wrapHeight ? 0 : height;

        // The pre-existing content of this view didn't match the current URL. Load the new image
        // from the network.
        ImageLoader.ImageContainer newContainer = mImageLoader.get(mUrl,
                new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (mErrorImageId != 0) {
                            setImageResource(mErrorImageId);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(final ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                        // If this was an immediate response that was delivered inside of a layout
                        // pass do not set the image immediately as it will trigger a requestLayout
                        // inside of a layout. Instead, defer setting the image by posting back to
                        // the main thread.
                        if (isImmediate && isInLayoutPass) {
                            post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    onResponse(response, false);
                                }
                            });
                            return;
                        }

                        if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                            setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                        } else if (mDefaultImageId != 0) {
                            setImageResource(mDefaultImageId);
                        }
                    }
                }, maxWidth, maxHeight, scaleType);

        // update the ImageContainer to be the new bitmap container.
        mImageContainer = newContainer;
    }

    private void setDefaultImageOrNull() {
        if (mDefaultImageId != 0) {
            setImageResource(mDefaultImageId);
        } else {
            setImageBitmap(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        loadImageIfNecessary(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        if (mImageContainer != null) {
            // If the view was bound to an image request, cancel it and clear
            // out the image from the view.
            mImageContainer.cancelRequest();
            setImageBitmap(null);
            // also clear out the container so we can reload the image if necessary.
            mImageContainer = null;
        }
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * In case the bitmap is manually changed, we make sure to
     * circle it on the next onDraw
     */
    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        mCircled = false;
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }

    /**
     * In case the bitmap is manually changed, we make sure to
     * circle it on the next onDraw
     */
    @Override
    public void setImageResource(int resId) {
        mCircled = false;
        super.setImageResource(resId);
    }

    /**
     * In case the bitmap is manually changed, we make sure to
     * circle it on the next onDraw
     */
    @Override
    public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        mCircled = false;
        super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }

    /**
     * We want to make sure that the ImageView has the same height and width
     */
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable != null) {
            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int diw = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            if (diw > 0) {
                int height = width * drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() / diw;
                setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
            } else
                super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        } else
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //Let's circle the image
        if (!mCircled && getDrawable() != null) {
            Drawable d = getDrawable();
            try {
                //We use reflection here in case that the drawable isn't a
                //BitmapDrawable but it contains a public getBitmap method.
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) d.getClass().getMethod("getBitmap").invoke(d);
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    Bitmap circleBitmap = getCircleBitmap(bitmap);
                    setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Seems like the current drawable is not a BitmapDrawable or
                //that is doesn't have a public getBitmap() method.
            }

            //Mark as circled even if it failed, because if it fails once,
            //It will fail again.
            mCircled = true;
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    /**
     * Method used to circle a bitmap.
     *
     * @param bitmap The bitmap to circle
     * @return The circled bitmap
     */
    public static Bitmap getCircleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        int size = Math.min(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(size,
                size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        BitmapShader shader;
        shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP,
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAlpha(254);

        RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, size, size);
        int radius = size / 2;
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, paint);
        return output;
    }
}
```

I came up with that solution, but I didn't like it, because the image loses its quality:

```
public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_user);
        camera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera);
        fechar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fechar);
        editar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editar);
        membro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.membro);
        nome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nome_usuario);
        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_usuario);
        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_usuario);
        profilePic = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.foto);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cropped);
        progress_wheel = (ProgressWheel) findViewById(R.id.progress_wheel);


        camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder getImageFrom = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserActivity.this);
                getImageFrom.setTitle("Abrir com:");
                final CharSequence[] opsChars = {getResources().getString(R.string.takepic), getResources().getString(R.string.opengallery)};
                getImageFrom.setItems(opsChars, new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (which == 0) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                            mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                    "tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

                            intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);

                            try {
                                intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else if (which == 1) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent();

                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                getImageFrom.show();

            }
        });


        profilePic.setImageUrl(GlobalModel.getPerfil().getIdDaImagem(), imageLoader);
        profilePic.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.avatar_);

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {

            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

            switch (requestCode) {
                case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
                    profilePic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    progress_wheel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    selectedImagePath = ImageFilePath.getPath(getApplicationContext(), mImageCaptureUri);
                    Log.i("Image File Path", "" + selectedImagePath);
                    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.parse(selectedImagePath);

                    final BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    option.inSampleSize = 8;

                    Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageCaptureUri.getPath(), option);


                    photo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, 200, 200, false);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);


                    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator + "Imagename.jpg");
                    f.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();

                    previewCapturedImage(f.getAbsolutePath());
                    profilePic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    progress_wheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    profilePic.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageCaptureUri.getPath()));

                    break;

                case PICK_FROM_FILE:

                    profilePic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    progress_wheel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
                    selectedImagePath = ImageFilePath.getPath(getApplicationContext(), mImageCaptureUri);
                    Log.i("Image File Path", "" + selectedImagePath);
                    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.parse(selectedImagePath);

                    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inSampleSize = 8;

                    Bitmap photoGaleria = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageCaptureUri.getPath(), options);


                    photoGaleria = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photoGaleria, 200, 200, false);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytesG = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    photoGaleria.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytesG);


                    File fG = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator + "Imagename.jpg");
                    fG.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream foG = new FileOutputStream(fG);
                    foG.write(bytesG.toByteArray());
                    foG.close();

                    previewCapturedImage(fG.getAbsolutePath());

                    profilePic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    progress_wheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    profilePic.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageCaptureUri.getPath()));

                    break;



            }


        } catch (Exception e)

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }




    private void previewCapturedImage(String path) {
        try {

            UploadFoto mUpload = new UploadFoto(path);
            mUpload.setEventoListener(new IExecutarTarefa<UploadFoto>() {
                @Override
                public void AntesDeExecutar(UploadFoto tarefa) {

                }

                @Override
                public void DepoisDeExecutar(UploadFoto tarefa) {

                    if (tarefa.getResposta()[0].equals("200")) {
                        GlobalModel.getPerfil().setIdDaImagem(WebService.imgURL + tarefa.getResposta()[1].replace("\"", ""));
                        profilePic.setImageUrl(GlobalModel.getPerfil().getIdDaImagem(), imageLoader);
                    }
                }
            });
            mUpload.execute();

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_back, R.anim.animation_back_leave);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        CarregarPerfil mCarrega = new CarregarPerfil();
        mCarrega.execute();
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_user"
        layout="@layout/toolbaruser" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/campoImagem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_user"
        android:background="@color/armadillo">


        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/foto"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/user"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <com.pnikosis.materialishprogress.ProgressWheel
            android:id="@+id/progress_wheel"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            wheel:matProg_barColor="@color/white"
            wheel:matProg_progressIndeterminate="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cropped"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/camera"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_camera" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Button_crop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="Salvar"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/membro"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Membro Retornar desde Julho de 2015"
            android:textColor="@color/star_dust" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/campoImagem"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Nome"
            android:textColor="@color/star_dust"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nome_usuario"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/armadillo"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/entrar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="E-mail"
            android:textColor="@color/star_dust"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email_usuario"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="jgvidotto@gmail.com"
            android:textColor="@color/armadillo"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text1" />


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: From debugging do you know if the image is getting loaded to memory the first time but only not rendering?

Comment: @DanS no, the image is not loading from the first time, I just realize that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have not posted your Activity calling the Navigation Drawer, so I have used both your `CircledNetworkImageView` class and built-in `NetworkImageView` in my project. It works well. Please refer to the following:

**CustomNavigationDrawer.java:**

```
public class CustomNavigationDrawer {
    private static ActionBarDrawerToggle sDrawerToggle;

    public static DrawerLayout setUpDrawer(final Context context) {
        final Activity activity = ((Activity) context);
        DrawerLayout sDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        if (activity.getActionBar() != null) {
            activity.getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            activity.getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }

        sDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                activity,
                sDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
                syncState();
            }
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
                syncState();
            }
        };

        sDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(sDrawerToggle);
        return sDrawerLayout;
    }

    public static void syncState() {
        sDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    public static void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        sDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    final Context mContext = this;
    final String mUrl = "http://.../getimage";
    NetworkImageView mNetworkImageView;
    CircledNetworkImageView mCircledNetworkImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CustomNavigationDrawer.setUpDrawer(this);            
        mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.networkImageView);
        mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(mUrl, VolleySingleton.getInstance(mContext).getImageLoader());
        mCircledNetworkImageView = (CircledNetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.circleImageView);
        mCircledNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(mUrl, VolleySingleton.getInstance(mContext).getImageLoader());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CustomNavigationDrawer.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        CustomNavigationDrawer.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {            
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/networkImageView"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <com.example.networkimageview.CircledNetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/networkImageView" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

You can create a new sample project and use my sample code. Hope this helps!

Comment: So what is your problem, the image not load when navigation drawer open first time, or the low quality image? Where did you setup your navi drawer?

Comment: the image not load when navigation drawer open first time

Comment: I cannot find where you setup or call your navigation drawer in your code. IMO, firstly you should create a new sample project and use my code, of course with your Url which returns the image.

Comment: Ok, BNK I`'ll try your code and let you know if it worked

Comment: Getting the same bug, when the image width is less than its height it doesn't loads

Comment: You mean the image in portrait mode? How about landscape mode image, can it be loaded at the first time or not?

Comment: Have you created a new project and used my code with your only Url? IMO, you should review the lines of code that process or create the Bitmap.

Comment: I have just run my app with portrait mode image, it works fine. My Url looks like `String mUrl = "http://192.168.1.247/images/port.jpg";` As I commented above, you should review your own code at which you create or process the Bitmap

Answer (score 0):

`if (width == 0 && height == 0 && !isFullyWrapContent) {`

I guess the first you loadImage code will return because of this condition. The width and height is equal to 0 before the whole UI load success. log before this condition return.  Hope this can help you.